# using Max and Avg function together in SQL

Tags: sql, max, average

I have the following four tables containing student information, lecture information, attending lectures information and exams.

using the 
SELECT Student_id, AVG(marks) as average FROM exams GROUP BY Student_id;
I get a list of average marks obtained by each student.

How do i combine it with MAX function to get the ID, name, and average of students who has the highest average in the list?

### students

student_id
student_name

### lectures

lecture_id
lecture_name
ECTS

### attending_lectures

id
student_id
lecture_id

### exams

id
Student_id
Lecture_id
Marks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: mysql and oracle

Answer (score 0):

*You may use such a SQL with an `ORDER BY ... DESC` clause to get `MAX`*

***For MySQL :***

```
SELECT e.Student_id, s.student_name, AVG(marks) as "average" 
  FROM exams e
  LEFT JOIN students s ON e.Student_id = s.Student_id
 GROUP BY e.Student_id, s.student_name
 ORDER BY "average" DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

***For Oracle :***

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT q.*, row_number() over (order by "average" desc) as rn 
   FROM
  (
   SELECT e.Student_id, s.student_name, AVG(marks) as "average"           
     FROM exams e
     LEFT JOIN students s ON e.Student_id = s.Student_id
    GROUP BY e.Student_id, s.student_name
   ) q
 )
 WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but its not returning what i'm looking for.   
two of the students has average of 4, but your solution returns the one with average of 2.3333

Comment: @Faaeq you're welcome. Edited the case for Oracle. Are you sure that you included `desc` keyword for `order by` clause ?